# Is a negative version code for android application valid?

Tags: android

I'm working on an app publishing platform for android and I want to make sure whether using a negative versionCode for android applications valid? 
I tried it and it built and ran fine.

Comment: Yes, versionCode can be negative. It just has to be increased with each successive update, but its absolute value is completely arbitrary.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's valid. As android developer site says below:

> An internal version number. This number is used only to determine
>   whether one version is more recent than another, with higher numbers
>   indicating more recent versions. This is not the version number shown
>   to users; that number is set by the versionName attribute.
>
> The value must be set as an integer, such as "100". You can define it
>   however you want, as long as each successive version has a higher
>   number. For example, it could be a build number. Or you could
>   translate a version number in "x.y" format to an integer by encoding
>   the "x" and "y" separately in the lower and upper 16 bits. Or you
>   could simply increase the number by one each time a new version is
>   released.

[Source](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html)

Comment: yes I have read that, unfortunately google has not specified whether the version code can be negative or not.

Answer (score 0):

You uploaded an APK or Android App Bundle with an invalid version code; a version code must be specified and should be a positive integer.

This is the error you will receive if you upload an app with negative version code!..

Google Play only allows a positive integer to be versionCode